# MySQL provides rank number when sort?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Suppose I have a table as follows in MySQL:

`create table user(name varchar(20), join_time int(11) )`

Here is my question： when fetching the records in join_time DESC order, how can I get the rank number of each record?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, u.* 
from (select * from `user` order by join_time desc) u, 
     (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

Comment: Technically, that's a row number, rather than a rank number.  Though I'm not sure if the OP makes that differentiation...  So, +1 :)

Comment: Actually correct if the ranking IS based on the JOIN_TIME DESCENDING

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `row_number() over (order by something)` which will return back the row number based on a provided order clause, but I am not sure if it is available in mysql?

With some search found out there is no row_number function in mysql but there is many workarounds to name a one http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/09/13/rownum-simulation-with-mysql/